# Adjusting background color and spacing of a collection view background and cell spacing

Tags: ios, ios7, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have the following code for testing:

In viewDidLoad()

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollView.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];


// These are required
[self.collectionView setDataSource:self];
[self.collectionView setDelegate:self];



//[self.collectionView.layer addBlueGradient];

[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];

[self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];


}



- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 50;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(200, 200);
}
```

I have created a category of a CALayer gradient called addBlueGradient. How do I make that the back ground of the collection view (it's just black or change it to a uicolor)? How do I adjust the spacing between cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 _collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // for setting the collection background color
```

and for space

Getting the Section Spacing

```
– collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex:
– collectionView:layout:minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:
– collectionView:layout:minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:
```

Answer (score 1):

To add your gradient to your collection view:

```
CAGradientLayer *myGradient = [CAGradientLayer gradient];

// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// This assumes your collectionView bounds is not (0,0)
// when you rotate your device, you may need to update the frame
// of your gradientLayer for the orientation changes.
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
myGradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.collectionView.bounds.size.width, self.collectionView.bounds.size.height);

myGradientLayer.colors = @[
                              (id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor,
                              (id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor
                          ];

myGradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.0);
myGradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);

[self.collectionView.layer insertSublayer:myGradientLayer atIndex:0];
```

To set the spacing between cells, you may need to use a number of these delegate methods:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {

    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 9.0, 0, 9.0);

}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.0;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.0;
}
```